# Is there a function in macro or VBA to extract data from cell with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way, if there is such, to compare two columns where in column A there are numbers, and in column B there is data. In Column B the data is something like "1 - the link to publication is missing; 2 - no signature given; 5 - no references;".
If the first character from Column B matches the number in Column A, then extract from Column A starting from the matching number to ";".

I am pretty sure this can be done on Python, but have no idea about VBA or in macro in Excel, as I've been working a lot with Excel lately.

Thank you for your time and help!

Cheers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking if VBA has Loops and can evaluate boolean expressions? Yes, it has those. [For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) , [ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement), [Do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement), [While](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/whilewend-statement), [If](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements)

You would be looking for something like:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim MyValuesFromSheet1 As Collection
    Set MyValuesFromSheet1 = GrabValues(Sheet1)
End Sub

Function GrabValues(WS As Worksheet) As Collection
    Dim SavedValues As New Collection

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = WS.Columns(1).Cells(WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Set SearchRange = WS.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In SearchRange
        If Cell.Value <> "" And Cell.Value = Left(Cell.Offset(, 1), 1) Then SavedValues.Add "that extracted region you described"
    Next
    Set GrabValues = SavedValues
End Function
```